# How to give focus to a TextInput programmatically in Actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, textinput

I am trying to write a small piece of Actionscript that gives focus to a TextInput. The reason being, I don't want my user to have to click into the text field to see the cursor and start typing, it should just already be there.

I've looked around for tutorials and other questions here on Stackoverflow and I can't seem to find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UIComponent instances in ActionScript 2 support `setFocus()`.  So

```
myTextInput.setFocus();
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, man, you are awesome. Thanks so much, this was an instant fix. I wonder why it was so difficult for me to discover something so simple? Perhaps I was just using bad search terms... Thanks again!